# Can't find where to change add primitive operator properties

Tags: modeling

Though I am new to Blender, I am not new to modeling. Still there is one thing I am not finding in Blender 2.8 beta, and it's frustrating the hell out of me.

How the heck do I change the properties of a primitive during creation.

In Blender 2.79 I see the option to do this, during creation, in the bottom left corner of the screen, but I do not see it in 2.8.

For example, with the selector icon chosen, which seems to be the default upon opening, I go to Add > Mesh > Cylinder. The cylinder shows up on the screen, but I cannot find the properties to change the number of vertices/facets, the radius, the height, etc.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you,

Jim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see below. The properties you are looking for are under the drop-down menu in the bottom left corner of the viewport. In 2.79 the default shortcut was F6, but it does not work in 2.8.

[image]

Comment: Oh geez, it was collapsed, I didn't even see it. Thank you seetheshy.

Comment: One more related question, lets say I deselect the primitive before I am able to use these options, but I have NOT modified the prim yet. Is there a way to get back to this form, or another so I can change these properties?

Comment: @jlevine66 if you deselect the primitive, you cannot go back to the operator panel. You gonna have to edit manually or delete it and create a new one. Also, please kindly confirm my answer to your question above. Cheers

Comment: sorry seethesky, I just saw your reply... thank you. How do I confirm your answer, I must be blind... lol

Comment: @jlevine66 It is possible to get back to the options panel if one has just accidentally closed them by pressing f9. However once you've changed anything away from that object this is no longer an option.