# Changing dimensions of shapes in Blender 2.8

Tags: objects

For anyone who is using Blender 2.8 right now, does anyone know how I can change the dimensions of the shapes in Blender 2.8.

Take the sphere for instance: I want to change the number of rings and grids on the sphere, which was a process I usually did in 2.79b. Does anyone know how I can do this in Blender 2.8?

Comment: Do you mean the original parameters when you first add an object?

Comment: [cant find where to change add primitive operator properties](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133436/cant-find-where-to-change-add-primitive-operator-properties/133437#133437)